# I have a single phase induction motor, with no capacitor, and can't see the shaded pole. Can you help me understand how it starts or should start?

Tags: induction-motor, single-phase, hum

I have a small single phase, induction motor with no capacitor. It's not missing, so this has got me thinking it should be a shaded pole. However, I don't see the shaded pole and my motor is just humming. If I try to manually spin it, it's very difficult while powered up. What am I missing?

[image: Motor Label]

[image: Bottom Windings]

[image: Top Windings]

Comment: Can you see the cutaways in the pole pieces? There's a slot at one end with something in it : that's likely to be a copper wire - the shaded pole. I'm not clear why the other end of each pole has an increase in the gap but it's probably related.

Comment: The only two copper wires I see are the black and white and they seem to be the same length. The cardboard tube seems to just be filler to keep the wires from moving around. There were others that I pulled out that were firm against the white wire. The only other component that I see is the thermal resister. Could that be acting as the shade pole?

Comment: look at 10 o'clock in the second picture ... 10 o'clock and 4 o'clock in bottom picture

Comment: I see.. I think. You're saying the two bumps under the red paint are the shading rings? Any ideas why the rotor fails to spin? It hums and I it requires a lot of force to turn when powered. Spins easily enough when not powered.

Comment: It must look something like this under the paint

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Shaded_pole_detail.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shaded pole motor.

Location of shading rings shown in green
[image]

Trouble spinning could be bad bearings if feels like increased friction

If it feels like it's full of molasses it probably some electrical problem in the motor.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't eb bothered to edit photos last night.